# Sending data by using an HTTP server

Tags: android, http

I'm trying to create a LAN video call app. I created ParcelFileDescriptor using datagram socket and pass it to MediaRecorder and start recording but on client side unfortunately MediaPlayer can't play it. I read somewhere it could be possible using any http server and learn little bit about [NanoHTTPD](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) but I don't know how to send my video using http server. Anyone could suggest.

Comment: It is all pretty unclear what you want. What do you want the http server to send? And to whom? Who would ask the server someting? And in which way?

Comment: From [here]:(http://programminglife.io/android-http-server-with-nanohttpd/) I learn how to send a html page from http server running on android over LAN to connected devices. I'm searching for anyway to send live video from camera or  any saved video in the phone for live stream by web browsers.

Comment: You can very easy send files with nanohttpd. So also video files.

Comment: I don't know how to send a file with nanohttpd do you have any link

Comment: You should have read all pages of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nanohttpd

Answer (score 0):

You open an InputStream `is` or FileInputStrem `fis` for the wanted file.

Then you can serve it like

```
return new NanoHTTPD.Response(Status.OK, "text/html", fis);
return new NanoHTTPD.Response(Status.OK, "image/jpeg", fis);
```